# Dispatcher not dispatching

Tags: c#, wpf, task, dispatcher

I wanted to test something so I built a small view & viewmodel with a Button and a ListBox.
When I click the button I run the RunCommand as in the code below. I don't understand why the Dispatcher doesn't fire the action I want it to run.

Here is the viewmodel code:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    private ObservableCollection<string> _items = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    private ICommand _runCommand;

    public ICommand RunCommand { get { return _runCommand ?? (_runCommand = new ActionCommand(RunCommandAction)); } }

    private void RunCommandAction()
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            if (Thread.CurrentThread == EnvironmentData.UIThread)
                _items.Add("Eldad");
            else
                Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => _items.Add("Eldad")));
        });
    }

    public IEnumerable<string> Items
    {
        get { return _items; }
    }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        _items.Add("Shahar");
    }
}
```

Any ideas will be great

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by doesn't fire the action ? RunCommandAction is not called at all ? Also please add the xaml where you declared the button and used the command.

Comment: Your action is designed to do everything in UI thread. It doesn't make any sense, IMO.

Comment: Why do you think that your action doesn't fire?  I suspect that your action is firing, but you're testing it through a UI that is bound to your `Items` property.  Since you don't implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, and your `Items` property doesn't return type `ObservableCollection`, your UI isn't going to update.  Try changing your `Items` property to type `ObservableCollection` and test again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher - Gets the Dispatcher for the thread
>   currently executing and creates a new Dispatcher if one is not already
>   associated with the thread.

Since you used Task.Factory.StartNew the thread that executes this is not the main thread.
If you want to use the Dispatcher for the UI thread you have to use App.Current.Dispatcher

Comment: This doesn't conform the question. If `Items` property is bound to any control, then `Dispatcher` from the non-UI thread would cause exception. But OP says, that action doesn't fire at all.

Comment: @Dennis, The Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher used by the OP is from another thread and if the code execution goes on the else branch the Action will not be executed. If you check the DispatcherOperation returned by BeginInvoke it should always be in Pending state. This could mean what the OP is referring as " the Dispatcher doesn't fire the action ".

Comment: Thanks - that solved it - I always thought that Dispatcher (as I wrote it) always goes to the UI thread.

Comment: @AdrianFaciu reply is corrent. the `_items` collection is an `ObservableCollection` items cannot be added to the observable collection from an another thread than the one on which it was created; so in the OPs case there was an exception inside the `Task` which was not bubbled and hence he perceived as the action not being fired.